# Submit separate binaries for iphone and ipad

Tags: ios, application-loader

How do I submit two separate binaries (one for iphone, one for ipad) in application loader? I'm using Ansca Mobile's Corona which doesn't support universal binaries.

Answer (score 0):

A universal app is supposed to contain one binary that works with both iPads and iPhones -- you don't submit two binaries.

I do wish there was a way to do so, actually, as that would make it easier to submit separate versions of the app and price each of them differently...